# ("vector subscript out of range") for Binary search problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, binary-search

I am trying to implement binary search function in C++, in this function I have sorted vector of integers, then I enter vector of integers to check the index of the value I am searching for, If value is not found -1 should be returned

The problem is I receive message _DEBUG_ERROR("vector subscript out of range"); while debugging.

Here is the code

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

int binary_search(const vector<int> &a, int x, int left, int right) {
    left = 0;
    right = (int)a.size();
    if (left > right) return -1;
    int mid = (left + ((left - right) / 2));
    if (a[mid] == x)
    {
        return mid;
    }
    else if (x > mid)
    {
        return binary_search(a, x, mid + 1, right);
    }
    else if (x < mid)
        return binary_search(a, x, left, mid - 1);
}

int linear_search(const vector<int> &a, int x) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        if (a[i] == x) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }
    int m;
    std::cin >> m;
    vector<int> b(m);
    int left =0;
    int right= (int)a.size() - 1 ;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        std::cin >> b[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m-1; ++i) {

        std::cout << binary_search(a, b[i], left, right) << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: `right` should be initialized to `(int)a.size()-1`. No wait. Since this is a recursive implementation of binary search, you don't have to initialize `left` and `right` inside the function. Their values come from the previous call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with this code:

In the binary search function, you start with assigning your parameters with new values, which will lead to infinite recursion. Just remove this assignment.

Your mid is assigned like this `int mid = (left + ((left - right) / 2));` but should be this: `int mid = (left + ((right - left) / 2));` (your current mid is always less or equal to left, and your error comes up here, since you try to use negative index)